# How can I remove the nav between content and content?

Tags: css, html

I'm writing a website and I'm having problems. Here is the code (the slider works, but not on codepen): [link](https://codepen.io/roma321/pen/EbqzPo)

```
(Between nav and content a big indent) I do not need this indent
```

1st problem: How to stretch nav to the whole page (width: 100% does not help)? (At the moment, not all of the place is occupied)

2nd problem: There is an indentation between nav and content. How to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the code snippet on fullpage to view the changes. Changes:

i) nav ul has the following code added to make it flexible and stretch it to the entire width of the page using flexbox (floats has been removed as they are no longer needed when using flexbox):

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
justify-content: space-between;
margin: 0;  //Changing this to 0 removes the indentation b/w nav & content
```

ii) nav li has the changes of to let it grow and shrink depending on the viewport resize:

```
text-align: center;
flex: 1;
```

```js
var slideNow = 1;
var slideCount = $('#slidewrapper').children().length;
var slideInterval = 3000;
var navBtnId = 0;
var translateWidth = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);

  $('#viewport').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(switchInterval);
  }, function() {
    switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);
  });

  $('#next-btn').click(function() {
    nextSlide();
  });

  $('#prev-btn').click(function() {
    prevSlide();
  });

  $('.slide-nav-btn').click(function() {
    navBtnId = $(this).index();

    if (navBtnId + 1 != slideNow) {
      translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (navBtnId);
      $('#slidewrapper').css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      });
      slideNow = navBtnId + 1;
    }
  });
});


function nextSlide() {
  if (slideNow == slideCount || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
    $('#slidewrapper').css('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
    slideNow = 1;
  } else {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideNow);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow++;
  }
}

function prevSlide() {
  if (slideNow == 1 || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideCount - 1);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow = slideCount;
  } else {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideNow - 2);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
      'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow--;
  }
}
```

```css
/* This is a Header*/

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*This is a navbar*/

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #2b3030;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px calc(100%/7);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #12700c;
}


/*Content*/


/* This is a slider  */

#block-for-slider {
  width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#viewport {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#slidewrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% * 4);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#slidewrapper ul,
#slidewrapper li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slidewrapper li {
  width: calc(100%/4);
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.slide-img {
  width: 100%;
}

#prev-btn,
#next-btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
}

#prev-btn:hover,
#next-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prev-btn {
  left: 20px;
}

#next-btn {
  right: 20px;
}

#nav-btns {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide-nav-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 3px;
}

.slide-nav-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lalala</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">

  <div id="block-for-slider">
    <div id="viewport">
      <ul id="slidewrapper">
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"> </li>
        <li class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/1280x250" alt="" class="slide-image"></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="prev-next-btns">
        <div id="prev-btn"></div>
        <div id="next-btn"></div>
      </div>
      <ul id="nav-btns">
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
        <li class="slide-nav-btn"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I had another problem. When the navigation panel element has a lot of text, it looks very bad  [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/OzO99)

Comment: @RomaKoshin I'd recommend removing the border-left and border-right as I just did, it would make a hassle everytime if uneven height lists are there that's why it looks bad.

Comment: @RomaKoshin Mark the answer if it helped. Cheers